# Alfred Workflow Bash Script Fails

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, alfred

I have created a script to automatically switch my Spotify UI from a light-theme to a dark-theme using Spicetify. The code for this script can is found here,

```
cd /Users/MY_ID/spicetify_data;

FILE=/Users/MY_ID/spicetify_data/nord.ini

if test -f "$FILE";
  then
    #We are in light mode, so switch us into dark mode.
    mv config.ini default.ini;
    mv nord.ini config.ini;
  else
    #We are in dark mode, so switch us into light mode.
    mv config.ini nord.ini;
    mv default.ini config.ini;
fi

spicetify update restart;
```

> Note: this is in a file called replace.sh

I have attempted creating many different styles of Alfred workflow to get this command to work. I have had success if I set up an Alfred workflow to run this as a `Terminal Command`, but this will open up many instances of the terminal, which is something I want to avoid. So Alfred says that to prevent this, I should create a `Run Script` action, but when I attempt this, nothing happens, and the UI theme does not change (even though it does if I use the `Terminal Command` setting.

Does anyone know what I could do to try and fix this workflow and allow this script to execute from just a `Run Script` action?

Comment: First, check if the file is getting replaced as it should.  You can open up the directory and trigger the script in Alfred to see this.  Second, use the full path to `Spicetify`.  I suspect it’s not being run because it can’t find it.

Comment: @CJK Thanks for the help in figuring out the issue. Posted below you can find the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out to me by @CJK, I had not considered the fact that perhaps Alfred was not able to find Spicetify. So I ran the script using my hotkey for it. Then I *manually* ran the 'spicetify update restart' command, and it successfully updated the Spotify theme.

To make sure then that this would happen from the Alfred workflow, I changed the final command where I called Spicetify to this:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/spicetify-cli/0.9.5/bin/spicetify update restart;
```

Now when I run the Alfred workflow it successfully automatically changes the Spotify theme!

Comment: Tada!  In _Terminal_, just check you've got the best path for `spicetify`: enter `which spicetify` and hit return, and see what path is returned.  Use that.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to invest in environment variables for workflows and not hardcoding paths in them, see [official documentation](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/advanced/variables/) for an example.

Basically you click your workflows env vars
[image]

and then you setup your `PATH` as you'd like
[image]

In your example, it would be something like `/usr/local/Cellar/spicetify-cli/0.9.5/bin`

This makes your workflow a bit more generic and share-able.